# How to pass variable name as column name in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to pass a variable as a column name to filter condition in pyspark while reading the parquet file. 
Example:

```
    Var=date_1
    df-spark.read.load("s://location/").filter(col(date_1)>=upd_dttm)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

Var='date_1'
df = spark.read.parque('s://location/').filter(f.col(Var) >= upd_dtm)
```